# MSBuild: Merge information from different sources in one task

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, msbuild

I want to run the `<AL></AL>`task of MSBuild to create publisher policies. To this end, in my `csproj` file, I create a list of config file names:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
   <ItemGroup>
     <ConfigFiles Include="$(TargetDir)\*.config" />
   </ItemGroup>
   <AL 
      LinkResources="%(ConfigFiles.Identity)" 
      Platform="x86" 
      KeyFile="$(ProjectDir)\KeyFile.snk" 
      OutputAssembly="$(TargetDir)\%(ConfigFiles.Filename).dll" 
      Version="@(PolicyVersion)" 
   />
</Target>
```

This works perfectly fine, if I only need one version number `"@(PolicyVersion"`. But what if need different version numbers for each config file? I could retrieve the version number from an XML attribute in the config file, but I don't know how to do that so it is available for the corresponding correct item during the batch build.

I also tried the following: the config files are named `Policy.2.2xx.Mylib.config`. These are programmatically created. I created, in addition, a `Policy.2.2xx.Mylib.ver` or even `MyLib.ver` file holding the version information (which is the same for each `Mylib`, but may be different for other libs), which I can read using

```
<ReadLinesFromFile File="$(TargetDir)\MyLib.ver">
  <Output TaskParameter="Lines" ItemName="PolicyVersion" />
</ReadLinesFromFile>
```

but how can I now manage to associate the version information for `MyLib` (or `Policy.2.2xx.Mylib`) with the corresponding config file in the `<AL>` task? I tried to use `"%(ConfigFies.identity).ver"` as `ItemName`in the read -- it was my hope I could then access this information as `"$("%(ConfigFiles.identity).ver")"` in the `AL` taks, hence referring to the same msbatch loop, but this does not work cause dots are illegal in item names.

It is probably as simple as creating a new item group from two other ones, but by now I'm not experienced enough with this MS Build monster to get this done. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

(Note that I'm using VS 2008).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't exactly understand what you need.  I think you want to pull the version number out of the config file's name and pass that to the `Version` property of the `AL` task.

Create a target that wraps the call to `AL`.  Call the new target by batching on the `ConfigFiles` item group.  In your target, use string methods to pull out the version number:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <ItemGroup>
        <ConfigFiles Include="$(TargetDir)\*.config" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildThisFileFullPath)"
             Properties="LinkResource=%(ConfigFiles.Filename)%(Extension)"
             Targets="_AL" />
</Target>

<Target Name="_AL">
    <Error Condition="'$(LinkResource)' == ''" Text="Missing LinkResource property." />
    <PropertyGroup>
        <_OutputFilename>$(LinkResource.Replace('.config', '')).dll</_OutputFilename>
        <_VersionNumber>$(_OutputFilename.Replace('Policy.',''))</_VersionNumber>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <AL 
        LinkResources="$(LinkResource)" 
        Platform="x86" 
        KeyFile="$(ProjectDir)\KeyFile.snk" 
        OutputAssembly="$(TargetDir)\$(_OutputFilename)" 
        Version="$(_VersionNumber)" />
</Target>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Quiet obviously I need to practise a bit to get used to this kind of loop. This looks very much like it will do what I need -- I cannot try this earlier than Wednesday I guess, but I'm rather confident. Even if not, it will get me started. The '$(LinkResource)' should be '$(_LinkResource)', right?

Comment: Is it possible that this replace function will be available only as of MSBuild 4.0?

Comment: @Thomas I fixed the inconsistency with the $(LinkResource) property.  Also, I believe property functions (i.e. the Replace function) were added in MSBuild 4.0.  You can still build .NET 2.0 code with MSBuild 4.0, though.

Comment: The correct value for `MSBuild Projects` should be `$(MSBuildProjectFile)`. (See the remarks section here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229474.aspx)

Comment: @ChrisNash Unfortunately, no. `$(MSBuildProjectFile)` is the path to the project that was called when MSBuild.exe was invoked. If your targets are organized into separate files and imported, that won't work. It should be `$(MSBuildThisFileFullPath)`, which is the path to the current file. I've updated my answer.